# "You not getting admission in MIT would have been so bad" or "Your…"?

Tags: possessives

Which one is correct?

- > "You not getting admission in MIT would have been so bad"
- > "Your not getting admission in MIT would have been so bad"

Similarly:

- > "he not offering you any help is hard to believe"
- > "him not offering you any help is hard to believe"

Comment: I have heard both of your second examples in speech. In the first one, 'your' is being used to refer to a phrase, "not getting admission," rather than a noun. The second one I can't really explain, but it would be understandable (just not good English).

Answer (score -1):

For the first one you would say: You, not getting an admission into MIT would have been so bad. The second, him not offering you any help is hard to believe. Make sure to put an emphasis on the HIM and YOU in speech, so it sounds more natural in a conversation.